# ArcMap event to detect when a toolbar open/close with ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I have this code to know if a toolbar is displaying:

```
IApplication m_aplication = ArcMap.Application;

ICommandBar versionToolbar = GetToolbarByName(m_aplication, "esriArcMapUI.VersionToolbar");

if (versionToolbar.IsVisible()){
    versionToolbar.Dock(esriDockFlags.esriDockHide);
}
```

I can hide a toolbar, but I need to know when a toolbar is added to the desktop view, for example when the user check a toolbar in customize option:

[image]

I have this extension class:

```
public sealed class eManager : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension
    {
       protected override void OnStartup()
       {
            MessageBox.Show("on Start up eManager");
       }
    }
```

And this config extension:
[image]

but the event doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The status of the toolbar you can only check if your toolbar is part of an [extension](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IExtension.htm). There is a bit more work to implement. In `Add Item`-dialog in your Visual-Studio project you can choose the template `Application Extension (Desktop)` of `Extending ArcObjects` category.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question adding my extension class, and configuration. I put a message on start up, but it isn't showing.

Comment: don't use ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension, I meant ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IExtension, so you can implement the IExtensionConfig Interface and use from there the State-Member.

Comment: look here for the [State](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#esriExtensionState.htm)-Member

Comment: Thanks, I made a timer. But when a I have to change it, I gonna try with a IExtension class, and if works, I'll check your answer. Regards